# Bluetooth BLE: possible system

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a phone with BLE app (I will develop this app) and a bluetooth-beacon in my house. 
When I return at home, I want to see, on my phone "Hello Mark!" and now, the system (server + beacon) and my phone will start a data transfer.

Example: 
(on my phone) "Hello Mark!"
... phone push some data to my beacon+server ...
... my server (with beacon) push some data to phone ...
So, my phone will "wake up" from beacon+server

Is it possible? I think yes but where can I find an example (Android and, if possible, iOS).

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the help center, and try again. [ask]. You need to try it yourself and come here with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to create an application with BLE peripheral mode. BLE scanner can scan and detect nearby devices by getting UUID. you can write on BLE characteristic. please refer the below link

> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html